# : 'function' object has no attribute 'read' on jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I'm getting an error uploading a dataset  , and it shows an error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read' i am on jupyter
this is my output
[image: 1]

Comment: You left the parentheses off `getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").name("test").getOrCreate
```

assigns the **function** `getOrCreate` to the variable `spark`, which is not what you wanted.

Instead, you want to assign the **return value** of the function `getOrCreate` (i.e. a spark session) to the variable `spark`, so you need to call the function using a pair of empty parentheses:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").name("test").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i got this error Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.isEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM

Comment: @SaharHamadi this error relates to the fact that you have conflicting versions of pyspark and Spark. Most likely pyspark is 3.0 and Spark is < 3.0

Comment: i have spark 2.4 and python 2.7

Comment: @SaharHamadi how did you install pyspark?